# Proving the cyclicity of scalar triple product

Tags: vectors, inner-products, cross-product

I wanted to proof the property that box product of three vectors remain equal if we change vectors in cyclic manner.

i.e.
$$(\vec{a}\times \vec{b}).\vec{c}=(\vec{b}\times \vec{c}).\vec{a}=(\vec{c}\times \vec{a}).\vec{b}$$

I tried to proof using geometry (parallelepiped) and was successful in proving that $(\vec{a}\times \vec{b}).\vec{c}=(\vec{b}\times \vec{c}).\vec{a}\space\space$  but I wasn't able to proof $(\vec{a}\times \vec{b}).\vec{c}=(\vec{c}\times \vec{a}).\vec{b}$ 
Please explain how can I prove this using geometry (if possible).

Alternative proofs are also welcomed.

Comment: What do you mean by first pair and third pair? Which equalities do you have and which are you having trouble with?

Comment: @AHusain I have made my question more clear. Take a look.

Comment: Try the equality $(b \times c) \cdot a = (c \times a) \cdot b$ first instead. Remember you are free to rename the variables.

Comment: @Spencer If you proved the first equality, just write it for $\,a'=c, b'=a, c'=b\,$ and see what you get.